# Java Format Output to Console / JTextArea with Multiple string values

Tags: java, string, swing, format, tabular

Have a program which I'd like output the values from an Array. Using tab (\t) or formatting e.g (%40s) doesnt account for strings of different lengths.

Current Code Below is Fine for the Headings.

```
    System.out.format("%s%40s%32s%32s%32s%32s\n","ID","NAME","SURNAME","POSITION","CONTACT","EMAIL");
```

However, Not for the values of different Lenths

I'd Like something like this below *****

```
Name         Surname         ID           Position
Joanne       Bassy           0000001      Manager
Mannnny      papsasjkasjnnxz 0000002      Boss
```

I Get this though *****

```
Name         Surname         ID           Position
Joanne       Bassy           0000001      Manager
Mannnny    papsasjkasjnnxz 0000002         Boss
```

Comment: could be possible only by using Monospaced Fonts and to use \t,

Comment: use JTable instead of bothering with and by remove lines in columns and rows (JTable API)

Comment: thanks for your response mKorbel

Answer (score 1):

Change your format string as follows:

1. Add a width specifier to the first format specifier to specify the width of the first column
2. Add a `-` flag on all the format specifiers to left align the values

The updated format string would be `"%-40s%-40s%-32s%-32s%-32s%-32s\n"`.

See the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more details.

Note that this solution has several limitations:

- It will only work when you use a fixed width font
- If any string is longer than the provided width, it will push the rest of the line out and the columns won't line up.
- The user will not be able to easily manipulate the data (column width, column order, sort order)
- The user won't be able to easily copy the output and paste directly into a spreadsheet.

Alternatives include

- Using a `JTable`, which would be more flexible but this would require more coding.
- Using `\t` to separate the fields instead of padding with spaces. This option would allow copying into a spreadsheet, but still has the other limitations and may be more difficult to line up the column values if they are not all roughly the same length.

Comment: Assumes a fixed width font.

Comment: Yes, I assumed a fixed width font as that is how the example was given. As @mKorbel notes, the best would be to use a `JTable` but if there is a restriction to using only text output this solution will work in conjuntion with a fixed width font.

Comment: +1 for addressing the question directly, but it wouldn't hurt to expand on the limitations and alternatives.

Comment: There arent any Limitations however, prefernce would be to use a text output option. Thanks   Rangi Keen / trashgod for yoyur Input